Condition if-else
I'm trying to send some data from a spreadsheet to a different one.
What I need is, if the text of the last row in column B is "APPLE" or "ORANGE" it should go to cell AA7 of the second sheet. In any other case, it should go to cell AC7.
I've created this script but the values always go to cell AC7.
Could you help me to see whats wrong with the script?
function comunicacion() {

//Destination sheet
var parte = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("url");
var datos = parte.getSheetByName('DATOS');
//Origin sheet
var origen = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ws = origen.getSheetByName('REGISTRO');

  var insertarFilaEncima = datos.insertRowsBefore(7,1);

//Datos obtenidos
var ultimaFila = ws.getLastRow();

var tipoComunicacion = ws.getRange(ultimaFila,2).getValue();



if(tipoComunicacion === "APPLE" || "ORANGE") {
datos.getRange("AC7").setValue(tipoComunicacion);
}
else (datos.getRange("AA7").setValue(tipoComunicacion))

}



Can you provide sample data or a set of values in your Sample Sheet where the code is being tested. It is working on my end, so I am thinking that you are encountering this issue due to proper casing and Upper case. You can use toLowerCase(), toUpperCase().

The data goes to the original sheet when a Google Form is answered. The question is a dropdown and all the letters are uppercase with no space at the begining or at the end.

Handling Multiple Conditions in If Statement
There is an error in your condition it will always return true due to the syntax use, ORANGE will always be treated as a standalone true value.
if(tipoComunicacion === "APPLE" || "ORANGE") 

The If statement below will check if it equals Either "APPLE" or "ORANGE"
if (tipoComunicacion === "APPLE" || tipoComunicacion === "ORANGE")

Sample Code:
function comunicacion() {

  //Destination sheet
  var parte = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("Url");
  var datos = parte.getSheetByName('DATOS');
  //Origin sheet
  var origen = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = origen.getSheetByName('REGISTRO');

  var insertarFilaEncima = datos.insertRowsBefore(7, 1);

  //Datos obtenidos
  var ultimaFila = ws.getLastRow();
  var tipoComunicacion = ws.getRange(ultimaFila, 2).getValue();


  if (tipoComunicacion === "APPLE" || tipoComunicacion === "ORANGE") {
    datos.getRange("AC7").setValue(tipoComunicacion);
  } else {
    datos.getRange("AA7").setValue(tipoComunicacion);
  }
}

Sample Output:


Reference:
If else Statement

Wonderful, thank you very much!

If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept the answer
